# tx_news parent category required

Tags: typo3, tx-news

The following scenario: TYPO3 7.6, news articles (tx_news) with two-tier categories. Selection category is mandatory, but editors have often only selected subcategory. 1., is there a possibility that category level 1 must also be selected? 2., someone has a tip, as I can automate also the parent category can activate afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a good idea that both categories must be checked but it highly depends on your needs. If it is because of potential requests or output in the frontend, it is enough that the child category is checked.

As a solution I would change the rendering of the categories and use a select list instead of the tree and render the parent categories with the value `--div--`. If the `minitems` setting is set to **1** as well, the user will be required to select a subcategory as parent categories are then not selectable.

Comment: In this case, it is mainly needed for a search function (filter ke_search). Change the rendering as a selectlist is actually a good idea, but in this particular case, an article can be assigned multiple Main- und Subcategories simultaneously.

Comment: then I would still remove the parent categories and render the title like `Parent category name > sub category name`

Comment: Sorry, I have not expressed myself clearly enough: If an editor only selects the subcategory, then I have two problems: 1., in the showview, only the subcategory is displayed, it should also appear the parentcategory. 2., which is more important: If I put ke_search a filter on a parentcategory, then records with only the subcategory selected is not taken into the searchresults.

Comment: 1st can be fixed by a vH or just get parentCategoriy from selected one. 2nd can be fixed by using a custom indexer